# Declarar arreglo de 0<=N<=2000000

Tags: c++, array

**El programa se crashea**

Necesito declarar un arreglo de 2000000 elementos, ¿cómo se declara?

Problema

Escribe un programa que dada la lista de N números determine en qué posición queda el elemento a0 (el primero de la lista) después que ésta se ordena.

Entrada

Tu programa debe leer del teclado la siguiente información:
En la primera línea el número entero N, la cantidad de números en la lista.
En la segunda línea los N números de la lista separados cada uno por un espacio.

Salida

Tu programa debe escribir en la pantalla un único número entero que representa la posición final del elemento a0a0 en la lista ordenada.

Restricciones: 1<=N<=2,000,000 y 0≤M≤10^9

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    int main(){
        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        int a,aux,i,j,e;
        cin>>a;
        int v[2000000];
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)cin>>v[i];
        e=v[0];

         //Bubble sort
        for(i=0;i<a-1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<a-1;j++){
                if(v[j]>v[j+1]){
                    aux=v[j];
                    v[j]=v[j+1];
                    v[j+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }
        int min=0,max=a-1,mit;

         //Búsqueda Binaria
        while(min<=max){
            mit=(min+max)/2;
            if(e==v[mit]){
                cout<<mit<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(e>=v[mit]){
                min=mit+1;
            }
            else if(e<=v[mit]){
                max=mit-1;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: creo que deberías usar el [quickSort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) para ordenar la lista porque  el costo de tu algoritmo es cuadrado y al ser demasiado grande, crachea

Comment: Pero es que no me deja iniciar el programa, al ejecutarlo, deja de funcionar.

Comment: deberías usar un arreglo más pequeño o debuguear tu problema a ver en cual punto de ruptura crachea

Comment: El nombre de este sitio es la respuesta: "Stack Overfow". Por regla general, no debería crearse en la stack un array (o cualquier objeto) de más de 1MB. El tamaño de la stack puede establecerse en el linker pero un array de 2000000 de elementos es seguro que debe crearse en la memoria libre (usando new, por ejemplo)

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila tenías razón con respecto a usar quicksort, y respecto al declarar el vector, solo lo declare con el tamaño del primer valor ingresado y funcionó perfectamente!, muchas gracias

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila ¿podrías explicar por favor cómo un bucle puede provocar el cierre de una aplicación simplemente por tardar mucho?

Answer (score 4):

> Necesito declarar un arreglo de 2000000 elementos, ¿Cómo se declara?

#### Problema.

Por lo que veo en tu código, estás declarando el arreglo en la pila:

```
int main(){
    // ...
    // ...
    int a,aux,i,j,e;
    // ...
    int v[2000000];
 // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 // todas las variables automaticas se crean en la pila
```

Este tipo de memoria está pensada para almacenar datos pequeños<sup>1</sup> pero al pedir dos millones de enteros estas pidiendo ocho millones de bytes (unos 7,6Mb) que es mucho más de lo que la pila suele poder almacenar.

#### Solución.

Usa memoria dinámica:

```
int main(){
    // ...
    // ...
    int a,aux,i,j,e;
    // ...
    int *v = new int[2000000]{}; // Memoria dinámica
```

No olvides liberar la memoria al acabar:

```
delete[] v;
```

#### Mejora.

Utiliza la clase [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
int main(){
    // ...
    // ...
    int a,aux,i,j,e;
    // ...
    std::array<int, 2000000> v{{}}; // Dos millones de enteros con valor 0.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>El tamaño de la pila depende de la implementación del compilador, pudiendo variar entre compiladores. Por ejemplo, mi versión de Visual Studio usa una pila de 1Mb que suele ser suficiente para alojar cualquier variable requerida por una función.

Comment: No comprendo, como es que las variables de una función se almacenan en la pila? tenia entendido que los parámetros de una función se ponen en la pila al momento de llamarla, pero que se carguen a la pila me es sospechoso :P . Donde hay mas información de este tema?

Comment: C++ dispone de dos "*tipos*" de memoria: automática (la pila o *stack*) y dinámica (el montón o *heap*). Todo lo que no va a memoria dinámica va a estática. La memoria dinámica se solicita con `new`, la automática al declarar un objeto. [Esto forma parte del funcionamiento intrínseco de C++](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

Comment: Para un tamaño fijo casi sería mejor usar `std::array`, ¿no?

Comment: Ciertamente @eferion lo edito.

Answer (score 1):

```
int v[2000000];
```

Con esa inocente línea estás creando en la pila de la aplicación un array de 8.000.000 Bytes o, lo que es lo mismo, 7.62 MB. La pila de un programa suele tener un tamaño limitado y no suele ser demasiado grande... de hecho la que viene por defecto con VisualStudio creo recordar que ronda el MegaByte.

Lo que está sucediendo es que esa instrucción llena la pila del programa y la desborda y eso provoca que la aplicación muera súbitamente (el Sistema Operativo mata la aplicación para evitar que corrompa memoria de otras aplicaciones).

La solución pasa por usar memoria dinámica:

```
int *v = new int[a];

// ...

delete[] v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se que tu duda es como declarar arreglos grandes, pero dado el problema:

> Escribe un programa que dada la lista de N números determine en qué posición queda el elemento a0 (el primero de la lista) después que ésta se ordena.

No ocupas guardar los N elementos en memoria, únicamente ocupas un contador que inicie en 0 y cada vez que se ingrese un numero mayor al primero incrementas tu contador. Al final el contador tendrá el valor de la posición que tendría el primer elemento si hubieras ordenado todos los elementos.

Algo como esto:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    int n,pos=0,num,inicial;
    cin >> n  >> inicial;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        cin >> num;
        if(num < inicial)
            ++pos;
    }
    cout << pos << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

De esta manera te ahorras espacio en memoria, ordenar los elementos y la búsqueda que haces después.